# why vxworks register r3 is falsified before execution?

Tags: exception, vxworks

I am going to run an application on a `PowerC` platform(vxworks), but I have encountered a problem. I've got a data access exception. register r3 is falsified before execution,

I don't know why, please help me with this question, thanks!

> 0x7ff7150 (tTask4_nor): Watchdog for T0 stopped 0x7ff7150
>   (tTask4_nor): CPU exception! Vector: 0x300 Task: 0 MSR: 0x2029230 CR:0x48000882
>   data storage Exception current instruction address: 0x07852fb4 
>   Machine Status Register: 0x02029230
>   Data Exception Address Register: 0xdc7a557c
>   Condition Register: 0x48000882
>   Exception Syndrome Register: 0x00800000
>   Task: 0x7ff7150 "tTask4_nor" 0x8131870 (ExcRecord):
>   exeExcRecord running now! 0x8131870 (ExcRecord): exeExcRecord have been done!
>   0x7ff7150 (tTask4_nor): task 0x7ff7150 has had a failure and has been stopped.
>   0x7ff7150 (tTask4_nor): The task has been terminated because it triggered an exception that raised the signal 11.

Register:

```
r0    = 0x05bfd934    sp    = 0x07ff7058   r2    = 0x004b93f0
r3    = 0xdc7a557c   r4    = 0x05bfd941   r5    = 0x00000000
r6    = 0x00000000   r7    = 0x00000000   r8    = 0x00000000
r9    = 0x05de550c   r10    = 0x00000001   r11    = 0x05bfd900
r12    = 0x00000708   r13    = 0x00536930   r14    = 0x00000000
r15    = 0x00000000   r16    = 0x004c2198   r17    = 0x004eac48
r18    = 0x004ea988   r19    = 0x004ea98c   r20    = 0x004ea990
r21    = 0x004ea994   r22    = 0x004ea998   r23    = 0x00000002
r24    = 0x004eabd8   r25    = 0x004eaa48   r26    = 0x004eaf94
r27    = 0x00000000   r28    = 0x004f0000   r29    = 0x05de550c
r30    = 0x005812a4   r31    = 0x00582b40   msr    = 0x02029230
lr    = 0x001df25c   ctr    = 0x001ea654   pc    = 0x07852fb4
cr    = 0x48000882   xer    = 0x00000000   pgTblPtr   = 0xeeeeeeee
asid    = 0x00000001   spefscr    = 0x00200000
```

Disassembly:

```
 0x7852f94  98640000    stb         r3,0(r4)
 0x7852f98  7c0802a6    mfspr       r0,LR
 0x7852f9c  9421fff8    stwu        r1,-8(r1)
 0x7852fa0  9001000c    stw         r0,12(r1)
 0x7852fa4  3c6005de    lis         r3,0x5de # 1502
 0x7852fa8  6063557c    ori         r3,r3,0x557c
 0x7852fac  3c0005bf    lis         r0,0x5bf # 1471
 0x7852fb0  6000d934    ori         r0,r0,0xd934
*0x7852fb4  90030000    stw         r0,0(r3)
 0x7852fb8  3c000015    lis         r0,0x15 # 21
 0x7852fbc  600088b4    ori         r0,r0,0x88b4
 0x7852fc0  7c0803a6    mtspr       LR,r0
 0x7852fc4  4e800021    blrl        
 0x7852fc8  8001000c    lwz         r0,12(r1)
 0x7852fcc  7c0803a6    mtspr       LR,r0
 0x7852fd0  38210008    addi        r1,r1,0x8 # 8
```

[image]

Comment: Please check your code, clearly something is wrong in your code causing a data access violation (Signal 11). Based on disassembly pinpoint to exact  location of code and try to find our any rouge pointers etc. Also check on what happens when your Watchdog for T0 expires, may be there is some race condition happening.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later. But I have another question, how can I make a data access exception like this (r3 regisger is falsified by some reason) factitiously.

Answer (score 0):

```
pc    = 0x07852fb4,
```

so the code  is:

```
stw         r0,0(r3).
```

I think ,r3 is out of range

(r3    = 0xdc7a557c )

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Try to elaborate to make your answer clearer.